# Adding text to a cell in an xlsx OOXML file?

Tags: xml, excel, spreadsheet, xlsx

I've been looking at some of the xml files excel generates and have found to define the contents of a cell it does something like this:

```
<c r="ABC" t="s">
<t>1</t>
</c>
```

Where the  is referencing a sharedString.xml file elsewhere.

So my question is, is it possible to put the text content directly inside the tags? Like so:

```
<c>
<text>ABC</text>
</c>
```

Or do I always need to reference an external shared strings xml file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Where the is referencing a sharedString.xml file elsewhere.

It is in the subfile "xl/sharedStrings.xml". The value inside the "t" element is the index of the "si" element in "xl/sharedStrings.xml" (first index is 0).

> is it possible to put the text content directly inside the tags?

Yes, like this:

```
  <c r="ABC" t="inlineStr">
    <is>
      <t>Here is the text directly in the cell</t>
    </is>
  </c>
```